# Change terminal prompt color/theme in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I would like to change the theme in the integrated terminal on Visual Studio Code to this:

https://jmp.sh/hNda3rA

As you can see there is a background color on the prompt.

Where and how can I do this? I use Mac and zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to configure in VS code but in your shell. The style is called [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) and you can get it for zsh with [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh). Probably you have to install a [Powerline font](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) on your Mac and configure VS code to use it for the shell in order to render the prompt properly.